# How to express a set with sub-scripted integer elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, notation

Is there a way to express $$\{1_1,1_2,1_3,1_4,2_1,2_2,2_3,2_4,...n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4\}$$
In a more compact way? perhaps with set builder notation or "Big-U" notation?

Additionally, is it even conventional to write integers with integer subscripts? If not, should I use letters instead?

Comment: I suggest $$\{ a_i : 1 \le a \le n , 1 \le i \le 4 \}$$

Comment: To be clear, is $1_1$ different than $1_2$?  If these are both equal to "the number one" then why write it twice since with sets the number of times beyond the first it is written won't affect things.  Do you mean for this to be a multiset instead?

Comment: Essentially, I'm trying to represent something like a deck of cards, disregarding the suits. So that the value of the 2 unique elements are the same but they may be identified uniquely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it would be clearer to represent the elements as ordered pairs, so that
$$ i_k=(i,k)$$.

Then you could write

$$ S_n=\{\,\,(i,k)\,\,\vert\,\, 1\le i\le4,\,1\le k\le n\} $$

If you prefer to keep the $i_k$ notation, you could just use

$$ S_n=\{\,\,i_k\,\,\vert\,\, 1\le i\le4,\,\,1\le k\le n\} $$